# why to use kafka to store cdc data instead directly consume by spark?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, cassandra, oracle-cdc

I want to consume CDC data from multiple data sources for example cassandra, mysql, Oracle ...etc . I have gone through some documentation to stream cdc data to kafka and store data into topics . I was thinking can't I write spark programs to consume data directly from source , instead first pushing data into kafka topics and then spark program connecting to kafka topics to consume message further .
Here are my few questions , I am trying to figure out answer:

1. what is importance of using kafka in between instead directly consuming changed records from spark ?
2. using kafka in mid won't add some latency to system ?

Comment: Maybe because Spark doesn't have an available library to read cdc data and that data can be useful for other systems outside only Spark? Plus, that CDC data exists on the database server, where you probably shouldn't be running be running Spark code since it's meant to be distributed

Answer (score 0):

You certainly can write your own Spark apps that can consume the data but doing so feels like you're reinventing the wheel. Kafka is solving this for you so you don't have to.

In addition, Kafka supports taking input from various sources as well publishing the data to multiple subscribers including Spark apps.

With Kafka, it's easier to build apps since there are connectors available for most technologies. Cheers!

Comment: okay , thanks for sharing info ! just one question what is benefit of using kafka in mid other than it has connectors for multiple technologies and it can publish data into multiple subscribers .

Comment: if I have one source for example cassandra and I am consuming data from cassandra to aws s3 using spark , and for that I am using cassandra-spark connector , can you specify with this type of requirement how kafka can be helpful ?

Comment: As I stated, if you have a Kafka connector that can get data from the source, you don't have to write the code/app yourself to do it. That's the advantage. Cheers!